# Enable django's TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID on a single method

Tags: python, django

I've created a view that displays preview of other templates. I want to show the empty tags inside the templates, so I've included

```
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = '%s'
```

... on my `settings.py` file. However, I would only like to enable this setting for a particular view, not globally on my app.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.conf import settings

def myview(request):
    settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = '%s' # '%s' will get expanded to the variable name that was not found
    ...
    template = render(request, 'myview.html', {})
    settings.TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = ''
    return template
```

Please note that this is ugly. If another user requests a different page in the short time before you reset the TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID back to '', then they might see invalid tags being displayed. The [Django docs say specifically NOT to do this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#s-altering-settings-at-runtime), but there is also an [open ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14628) suggesting that it might be OK for some settings.

Hopefully someone smarter will come by and give a better solution.